# Is there a CSS approach to make dynamic data driven characters fit inside div button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am editing a data-driven website that uses data from an automation database engine. Inside the HTML, I have a fixed size button and within that are texts that come from the database. I want to add some css styles that would resize the font so that it always fits inside the div button.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.button { 
    width: 216px; 
    height: 44px; 
    background-color: 00baf2; 
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;

@media screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .button { 
        width: 400px;
        height: 81px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 40px;
        background-size: 400px 81px !important;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        margin: 25px auto; 
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="button">View Your Plan</div> (static/not data-driven)
<div class="button">Current Members Click Here</div> (data-driven)
<div class="button">Enroll Now</div> (static/not data-driven)
```

**The second/middle button is a data driven button. Sometimes, the words will be longer than "Current Members Click Here". Sometimes, it will be "See Your Plan Discount Program Here". The problem is if take out the font-size and line-height, it will default the font-size, which makes it small. How do I fix this so that the dynamic text will always fit inside the div button whether it is short or long? Can it be done with just CSS or is there a JS solution?**

Here is what it looks like now: 
Desktop View
[image: Bad Desktop]
Mobile View
[image: Bad Mobile]

Goal: 
Desktop
[image: Good Desktop]
Mobile 
[image: Good Mobile]

Comment: Why don't you padding the button?

Comment: just create additional class for class for data driven button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is a dynamic font size that scales to fit, and you can't do that with just CSS. You *can* apply different classes conditionally which could affect the font size. For instance:

```
.button.small-text {
    font-size:12px;
}
.button.medium-text {
    font-size:18px;
}
.button.large-text {
    font-size:23px;
}
```

You would need to redefine these in your media queries to fit the different button widths.

Then you have to either use backend or frontend script to apply `small-text`, `medium-text` or `large-text`.

With jQuery this might look like:

```
$('.button').removeClass('small-text medium-text large-text');
$('.button').each(function() {
    var len = $(this).text().length;
    if (len < 20) {
        $(this).addClass('large-text');
    } else if (len < 40) {
        $(this).addClass('medium-text');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('small-text');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution till now

Comment: I have tried this method and jQuery is adding the class to the div but not the properties so you see <div class="button large-text">[TEXT HERE]</div> but in dev tools I don't see any new properties or values.

Comment: nevermind. for some reason, adding the css properties directly under .button fixed the problem instead of having it at the end of the stylesheet. wonder why that would that happen?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I just read a comment that you want that data-driven button to have a smaller font than the others. Just specify it in the class I used for that button, setting a smaller vw in your font-size.

This is possible using VW units, you will need to support older browsers with a fallback though. I don't know if this breaks in larger desktops but hopefully you can get an idea of this approach.

```css
  .button {
    width: 216px;
    min-height: 44px;
    background-color: #00baf2;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
  }
  .button.data-driven {
    line-height: 22px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .button {
      font-size: 23px;
      font-size: 2vw;
    }
    .button.data-driven {
      line-height: initial;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .button {
      width: 400px;
      height: 81px;
      font-size: 30px;
      line-height: 81px;
      background-size: 400px 81px !important;
      float: none !important;
      clear: both;
      margin: 25px auto;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    .button.data-driven {
      line-height: 81px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="button">View Your Plan</div>(static/not data-driven)
<div class="button data-driven">Current Members Click Here</div>(data-driven)
<div class="button">Enroll Now</div>(static/not data-driven)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to remove the `height` to the button to make it dynamic. So the button will grow as the text increases. and do add a `display:inline-block` to the button class.

If you need to make the button with fixed/constant height, use a `%` value in the font-size of the button.
like `font-size:10%;` as `%` denotes a relative value, you could use that.

Comment: the button's height is constant in the OP's example